# Visual FoxPro report total pages

Tags: report, foxpro

I am able to get the total pages by doing steps as below:

REPORT FORM report NoConsole

lnMaxPages = _PAGENO

REPORT FORM report PREVIEW

but above only work if my report are all in the same group.

Let say I am printing 3 different reports (3 groups), and assuming each group have different pages. How do I display the correct lnMaxPages for each group?

Edit: I am using VFP 5 where there is no _pagetotal command.

Comment: To clarify.  You say 3 different reports (3 groups), which is it 3 distinct reports or 1 report that has data grouping, such as list all invoices and do subtotal per individual customer, and you want to know how many pages per specific customer.... OR, 3 reports and you want the total for ALL 3 reports, then show them out?

Comment: Just collect the information after each report and store it, say, in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a UDF that stores the number of pages (use a variable in the report that only increments for each group) for example, the page number you are on when you are in group 1/2 or 3.  Do some math and calculate the number of pages for each group.  This will get you the variables when you run it noconsole.  Display it on the report when you actually run it to the screen or printer.